# messaging Conversation php

Tags: php, mysql, chat, messaging

i have created messaging system, on messages.php i want to show messages conversation wise and last message should be displayed but don't know the query as i'm new to php here is the database information

> ```
>   table:conversation_chat            table2:chat
>  conversation_id: primary unique    id: primary unique 
>  from:                              conversation_id: 
>  to:                                from_user:
>  time:                              to_user:
>                                     message:
>                                      subject:
> ```

Please if Someone can help me in this

```
 <?php

  $req3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `conversation_chat` WHERE 
  `user_to`='$userid1'");
 $hy= mysql_fetch_array($req3);

  $convo = $hy['conversation_id'];

  if(mysql_num_rows($req3)!=0){

  $req4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `to`='$userid1' AND  

  `conversation_id`='$convo'");
      while($dn1 = mysql_fetch_array($req4))
   { 
  ?>

 <td><img alt="example image" src="avatar.png"> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a 
 href="read?id=<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?>"><?php echo
 htmlentities($dn1['from'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>



                  <td><span class="label vd_bg-green append-icon">

 <?php  
 echo $dn1['subject']; ?></span></td>
                  <td style="width:80px" class="text-right"> 

 <strong><?php echo timeAgo($dn1['time']); ?></strong></td><td 

 style="width:80px" class="text-right">
 <?php echo '<a 
 href="mdelete.php?id='. $dn1['id'] .'">Delete</a>'; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
 }}else{ echo "No new messages";}
 ?>
```

Comment: So you want to effectively reverse the conversation?

Comment: i want the last message to be shown in that conversation on messages.php with his name and message

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you just edited your database informations.
So now i understand how your database is.

You must add a "time" column  with DATETIME type in chat2"

```
SELECT * 

FROM `chat` 

WHERE `to`='$userid1' 

AND  

  `conversation_id`='$convo'    

ORDER BY time DESC //Change the order from last to older
```

If you only want the last message, and if its a MySQL database, you can add

```
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this will only fetch the name of the user who sent the message to me because in conversation_cat table only conversation id and users name is stored...i want the the name message and time from table 2 chat table

Comment: I edited my answer. First time i didnt understood your table informations due to wrong format.

Comment: it giving mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\twekr\messages.php on line 514

Comment: Did you add a 'time' column to you chat table ?

Comment: And so you have an error on this line right ? 

$req4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `to`='$userid1' AND  `conversation_id`='$convo' ORDER BY time DESC");

Comment: yess. sir i want each conversation last message to be shown on message.php for e.g if you 5 people messages me then it becomes 5 conversation and it should be shown....but if you message me 5 times then it become single conversation... you got my point??

Comment: Ok so you must add LIMIT 1 :  $req4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE to='$userid1' AND conversation_id='$convo' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1");

But it doesnt explain why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display one and only one message. Namely the latest?

If that is true change your query from

```
SELECT * FROM `chat` ...
```

To

```
SELECT *, max(date) FROM `chat` ...
```

Select

Comment: according to my question if 5 diffrent people message me then 5 messages should be diplayed on messages.php ...! but if 1 person messages me 7 time then his last message should be shown on that converstaion

Comment: I believe your database definition requires some more work to support that properly. Your second table should have the combination of id and conversation_id as the primary key and then the "id" in that table should be defined as a foreign key referencing the first table. Please google about "Relational Database Normalization".

If you skip that, your database will get messed up in time and it is almost impossible to fix it later. It is very well worth to spend lots of time into a good database definition. That will namely save you lots and lots of fixing effort later on.

Comment: E.g. Pay attention to the "from" column. It seems you have that in both tables and that seems to be a redundancy that you should remove.

After that you will find it much easier to formulate new queries using the SQL keywords "group by" and "join" to get what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

  $req3 = "SELECT DISTINCT conversation_id,column_name FROM `conversation_chat` WHERE 
  `user_to`='$userid1' ORDER BY conversation_id desc";
$query=mysql_query($req3);
$num=mysql_num_rows($req3);
 $hy= mysql_fetch_array($req3);

  $convo = $hy['conversation_id'];

  if($num!=0){

  $req4 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id,column_name FROM `chat` WHERE `to`='$userid1' AND  

  `conversation_id`='$convo' ORDER BY id desc ");
      while($dn1 = mysql_fetch_array($req4))
   { 
  ?>

 <td><img alt="example image" src="avatar.png"> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a 
 href="read?id=<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?>"><?php echo
 htmlentities($dn1['from'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>



                  <td><span class="label vd_bg-green append-icon">

 <?php  
 echo $dn1['subject']; ?></span></td>
                  <td style="width:80px" class="text-right"> 

 <strong><?php echo timeAgo($dn1['time']); ?></strong></td><td 

 style="width:80px" class="text-right">
 <?php echo '<a 
 href="mdelete.php?id='. $dn1['id'] .'">Delete</a>'; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
 }}else{ echo "No new messages";}
 ?>
```

Comment: order by id desc give you last id.

Comment: your query is ony giving one conversation list but in  database there are two

Comment: now this query give different-2 user message detail.

Comment: what is this column name?